# is it true no italics for iPhone 4?

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uilabel, italics

In my project, the iPhone 4 does not show italics for command

```
textLabel.font=[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:16];
```

but the iPhone 3 shows italics properly.

Is it true that iPhone 4 does not support italics? If not using systemFont, can you get italics?

thanks,

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly yes, it does not seem to work for the iPhone 4.  It was [blogged about at daring fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2010/06/4), who picked it up [here](http://nfarina.com/post/738543430/iphone-4-no-italics).

If I were you, the best thing to do would be to wait it out.  Apple will probably fix this issue during a future iOS update.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone 4 uses Helvetica Neue, whereas all prior versions of the iPhone and iPod Touch uses Helvetica. This has something to do with which one renders best on the retina and normal displays. For some reason Apple didn't include the italic files of the Helvetica Neue font, and I'm pretty sure this is a design related decision, so don't expect that to change. If you absolutely need italic in you application, I suggest you use another font.